# Is there a meaningful difference between Cyber Defense and Cyber Security?

Tags: terminology

I've been describing some entrepreneurial aspirations to people and one of them in the IT area interrupted when I said I was interested in starting a *"Cyber Defense"* firm, and he said *"Cyber Security"* is the proper term.

Is there a difference between using the *Cyber Security* terminology or the *Cyber Defense* term?

I mean, can I safely interchange both terms?  I believe not, since the former seems more encompassing, whilst the later seems to be just the passive side of security.

Comment: I don't think the Google results provide a lot of confidence. I was hoping to hear from someone who's been in the industry and knows if these words are used interchangeably by practicioners.

Comment: I think we have got off on the wrong foot here. Is cyber security/defense what you actually want? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4z5TpZvTcg4

Comment: Why would this be opinion based? If different people use the term differently, that would make a good answer, and not a close reason.

Comment: Paradoxically, if it is opinion based, wouldn't that be the answer to the question? @Dogeatcatworld I'm not sure what you mean. I want to know if the terms are considered interchangeable or not. And if no one knows, that would imply sufficient ambiguity to use them interchangeably.

Comment: You get to define your business idea however you want. You don't provide those details. What you appear to be asking is "what's the best description for my idea?" and that is an opinion question. If the context doesn't matter, then you might need to remove it.

Comment: My question is about how the terms Cyber Defense and Cyber Security are defined by practitioners and if there are important distinctions between them. The business idea part of it is not relevant.

Comment: @Anders - I agree that this may be slightly opinion based.  But I also agree with you that this may not be enough "opinion based" to warrant the close.  It can be answered from a terminology point of view.  I made a change to the question which hopefully will get it on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the term "cyber defense" is used to refer to the military/government side of cybersecurity.

Example.

> NATO and its Allies rely on strong and resilient cyber defences to fulfil the Alliance’s core tasks of collective defence, crisis management and cooperative security. [...] NATO signed a Technical Arrangement on cyber defence cooperation with the European Union in February 2016.

[Source](http://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_78170.htm)

Clearly, they are not talking about standard, corporate "cybersecurity".

Since cyber defence is mostly dealt with by governments and probably huge contractor companies, your firm wouldn't deal with it, which may be why you were corrected.

Comment: They name it defense and use it to attack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working in the InfoSec industy (Programmer, though) but in my region, there's a difference.

**Cyber Security** monstly refers to Penetration Testing and Forensics (How and Why did the attacker got into the system), whereas **Cyber Defence** deals with prevention of those attacks (Administration, ACS, etc.) But as far as I noticed, Cyber Defence is seen as a part of  Cyber Security

Comment: In some cases, Cyber Security refers to design while Defense to attack prevention by using various means.